# String incorrectly displays as split when printing, though no split is called

Tags: python, string, split, display

I am trying to print this simple line:

```
summary = str('Monthly payment complete. A total of ' + str(total_cents) + ' cents worth ' + '{:.2f}'.format(total_cents * 1000) + ' were sent to ' + str(len(recipients) - 1) + ' recipients.')
print(summary)
```

but the result displays on a split-line. Why is this happening?

Result in terminal below:

```
('Monthly payment complete. A total of 0.00105546 cents worth 11.00 were sent '
'to 2 recipients.')
```

Comment: I can't see how you could get such an output... In what environment are you running this code?

Comment: I checked your output result but it was shown in one line string.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille I wrote the code in a .py doc in Visual Studio Code and am running it in a zsh terminal on my Mac. This happened once before but I don't know what change I made that corrected the issue. It's now happening again. Very odd since the split is between a standard string and not at a concatenation break.

Comment: Maybe it's something specific to zsh? What happens if you use bash?

Comment: @ThierryLathuille I get the same result in bash. I'm also noticing that when I print a string, eg print('my\n name'), instead of printing 'my' and 'name' on separate lines, it prints 'my\n' and 'name' on separate lines (it includes the escape newline \n in the printed string). It feels like there's something very weird going on with my terminal output

Comment: Strange indeed... Can you edit your question to add this info, and include a short sample program and a copy of the complete terminal session that exhibits the problem?

Comment: @ThierryLathuille I feel sheepish. It was bugging me all day so I finally just went through every single line and realized I was printing a method that prints a line. If you print a function/method with a print statement, it looks like it doesn't observe the escapes. I think I can mark this issue as complete. Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The result is actually showing a single line. In python if two strings within brackets are only separated by whitespace characters they will be connected.

Try this in python:

```py
single_string = ('first line'
'second line')

print(single_string) # outputs 'first linesecond line'
```

Comment: Thanks @Marko, however, my issue is the opposite. In my scenario single_string = str('ab cd ' + ' ef gh'). When I print(single_string) I get output >> 'ab cd ef'  >>' gh' (on separate lines)

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer. I was calling a method inside a print() and that method contained a print() within it (not what it returns, just a line of code that prints something before returning the output).

When calling the method and printing it's output, the result was a print of a print and then a print of the method's output. The print of a print seems to have some issues maintaining formatting/escapes.

Comment: wut? Can you add some more details to your answer? As it stands, "printing a print()" is pretty unclear. Printing the return value of a function that itself includes a call to `print()` shouldn't do what your question shows.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi sure, I edited my response and tried to include more specific detail. Printing a method that contains a print() inside (but not the output) seems to have some difficulty.